# slf4j version conflict while building with Maven

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I realised that one of my projects uses slf4j 1.5.8 and Hibernate uses slf4j 1.6. While building with Maven it downloads both jars but I guess the class files of 1.5.8 are used. So, when I run the program i get following error:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
```

In `pom.xml` I have put

```
<dependencyManagement>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The 1.5.8 is part of dependency so it's downloaded on its own.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you discovered yourself, there are two libraries (Hibernate and some other) transitively importing SLF4J in two different versions. Unfortunately the older version is being picked up by maven (there are some rules which dependency should be chosen by maven in this situation). The solution is to add the `exclusion` in the dependency that imports older version of SLF4J (`com.example:foo-bar` is example here):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you still experience this problem, issue:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

Look for 1.5.8 version and exclude it from all libraries importing it.

Comment: Excluding is quite unnecessary. Instead, explicitly include the slf4j-api with the desired version in your projects pom file. That's it!

Comment: @Ceki If you don't exclude you can't be sure which version is picked up first.

Answer (score 8):

Excluding is quite unnecessary and maybe quite misleading. Instead, **explicitly** include the slf4j-api with the desired version in **your projects pom file**. That's it!

This approach takes advantage of Maven's transitivity rules: the nearest dependency declaration wins.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I have to exclude the transient dependency so I can specify my own.

Comment: @Ceki could you comment on end-user's experience?  Should this be possible without excluding?

Comment: It may be unnecessary but its documentation, it shows the users that you've altered a library that your other library expects. If theres an error there then it is clearer.

Comment: You are making assumptions which maybe incorrect, in particular you are not excluding a specific version whereas with my proposal you are including a specific version.

Answer (score 1):

you can exclude the wrong version with something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Fine but OP says that Hibernate imports correct SLF4J 1.6.1 version, so it is the other library that requires exclusion.