# Cannot configure Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, slf4j

I am trying to make a simple 'Hello World' application with Spring Boot. After following the tutorial from the [Spring website](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start), I am getting the following error:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
12:51:10.775 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/IdeaProjects/TestSpringFramework/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/3.0.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.1.12/ognl-3.1.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/attoparser/attoparser/2.0.3.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.4.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.6/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/3.0.2.RELEASE/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-acl/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-security-acl-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.11/logback-core-1.1.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.24/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.24/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.24/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.24.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.24/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.7/jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.7/jackson-core-2.8.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/nabil/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202017.1.1/lib/idea_rt.jar]
12:51:10.780 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService.<init>(RelaxedConversionService.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:630)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.bindToSpringApplication(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:235)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:336)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at SpringBootWebApplication.main(SpringBootWebApplication.java:14)
```

SampleController:

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController
{

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>BootExample</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've also tried adding an exclusion to the slf4j:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

But it didn't work either. Tried solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477942/slf4j-version-conflict-while-building-through-the-maven) but the problem remains. Any recommendation?

Comment: Did you try to do exactly the same code as the Spring Example ?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same; I tried the `SampleController ` class mentioned in the tutorial with the same code and the problem persists.

Comment: if I were you, I would rather follow this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Please add the maven resource tree

Comment: The classpath in the log output is very different to the classpath you'd get with the pom you've posted. For example, the classpath contains Thymeleaf 3, Spring Security, old Spring Framework 4.1 jars (Slring Boot 1.5 requires 4.3), etc. Are you sure that's the complete pom and that IDEA is using it correctly?

Comment: Maybe my question is silly, but, did you run `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean install -U` before to start up the project? I followed the same tutorial and it works

Comment: Did you try maven clean, update and install ?