# SLF4J + version 1.7.x by your slf4j binding is not compatible 1.6

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, slf4j, ambari

I am running the following application on my Linux machine
and we get the:

version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]

**important remark - we not have the file - pom.xml in my OS!!!**

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /opt/mcspace/evenacer/mc.kafka.debug.eventTracer.jar server /opt/mcce/evencer/appation.yml

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 45005


SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
```

what is the meaning about version 1.7.16 and 1.6?
what is 1.6 version?

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

dose pom.xml file that isnt exist in my OS maybe defined as other file name?

Comment: see please my update , but wait sec its complain about 1.7.x ? what is going here?

Comment: this can be helpful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477942/slf4j-version-conflict-while-building-with-maven

Comment: yes I already see that but I not have the file - pom.xml in my linux machine , or maybe I need to search some other file?

Comment: You have incompatible versions of the slf4j-api (version 1.6) and a specific logging implementation (version 1.7.16)

Comment: do you mean that we need to download the version slf4j-api with 1.7.x ?

Comment: so what is the solution ? need to replace the api file or something else ?

Comment: @Mark - please see my update , all answers was about pom.xml file , but we not have this file and we cant do this workaround

Comment: That you are not using Maven, just means that you can't fix it by editing the POM, but the basic solution remains the same: you have incompatible versions of dependencies: fix that.

Comment: so please help me to understand what I need to do ? I need to find api file from 1.7 version ?

Comment: please write your solution as answer so it will be more useful

Comment: another question please if my java version is 1.8.x so why its complain about - 1.7.16 ?

Comment: This is an ANSWER, @KingDavid: The error message is saying that your installed/configured version of SLF4J (check in the MANIFEST part of the .jar file) - v1.6 - is not compatible with the version requested by the "binding" (see https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping ) which is 1.7.16. Hence you should replace your current SLF4J jar with v1.7.16 (or later ?).  Other versions can be downloaded from https://www.slf4j.org/dist/