# Eclipse running SpringBoot: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven

Whenever I fire up a SpringBoot-based application (run as Maven build / goal spring-boot:run) I get the infamous SLF4J Warning:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/U:/eclipse/eclipse-jee/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/U:/eclipse/eclipse-jee/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/8/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

That warning annoys me greatly because when demoing an application from Eclipse the first thing the potential customers or users are seeing is a big red superfluous warning. I HATE that! It looks so unprofessional!

Now - in principle the warning is clear: there are two SLF4J bindings and one should get rid of one of them. I found misc. descriptions of the same error some of which also explain how to locate the (usually transitive) dependency and then exclude one of them from the dependencies in the pom.

I tried that and non of these suggestions worked for me! Also the solution proposed in
[Eclipse Maven: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518376/eclipse-maven-slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings) (namely to use an external Maven installation) did NOT work!

Looking closer at the paths listed in the warning I would claim, that there are already two bindings in eclipse itself (in the plugins org.eclipse.osgi... and in org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar) and that probably explains why my attempts were fruitless: mangling the application's pom doesn't change anything regarding these Eclipse-internal bindings. The mentioned append comes to the same conclusion: it's a bug inside eclipse.

But does anyone have an idea what it would need to get rid of that warning? I am open to all kind of "hacks"! Could one e.g. "massage" the ...m2e.maven.runtime.'s jar to no longer contain the org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class (or probably rather its containing jar)? Or are there better/safer ways?
What would be needed to get rid of that warning in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

for me [Eclipse Maven: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63518376/eclipse-maven-slf4j-class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings) work. In Debian Linux I add /usr/share/maven to Window/Preferences/Maven/Installations and these warnings disappeared.

Comment: As I wrote: I tried that as well. My path (on Windows 10) points to "C:\Program Files\Apache\Maven" but these "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings..." warnings (as shown in my initial question) still appear. :-(